# Can we think of information theory in terms of "a measure on set of information"?

Tags: information-theory

In information theory, we deal with the quantities $I(X;Y), H(X),H(Y), H(X|Y), H(Y|X)$. These are just numbers, but I intuitively think of them as the "measure" of a set of information.

There is at least one special case where this interpretation is exact: suppose there are independent variables $V_1,...V_n$, and the variables $X,Y,Z$ are *tuples of $V_i$*. Then we can literally think of $I(X;Y)$ as the **measure (entropy) of the intersection of $X$ and $Y$.**

But it is not obvious to me whether we can define a more general measure of information, such that mutual information can be interpreted as the measure of the intersection, and analogously for the other information quantities. **Is this possible?**

Comment: This article https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/03/01/special-cases-of-shannon-entropy/ shows that there is an analogy between entropy and cardinality of a set, but it breaks down in more complex scenarios.